# Characterizing non-degenerate subspaces of Minkowski space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am trying to show the following equivalence:

**Proposition 1.** A subspace $V$ of the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}_1^{n+1}$ is non-degenerate if and only if $\langle v, v \rangle \ne 0$ for all $v \in V$.

(I believe this proposition is true, although I'm not 100% sure. If it is true, then an easy consequence is every non-degenerate subspace is either timelike or spacelike, since we have Gram-Schmidt.)

Here my definition of non-degeneracy is given by

**Definition.** Say $V$ is non-degenerate if the Lorentz product restricted to $V$ is non-degenerate, i.e., for all $v \in V$, $\langle v, w \rangle = 0\ \forall w \in V $ implies $v = 0$. Or equivalently, say $V$ is non-degenerate if $V \cap V^\perp = \{0\}$.

So Proposition 1 above is essentially

**Proposition 2.**
$$
V \cap V^\perp = \{0\} \iff \forall v \in V, \langle v, v \rangle \ne 0.
$$

The $\Longleftarrow$ direction is trivial, but **I'm having trouble with the $\Longrightarrow$ direction.** Any thoughts on this direction? Thanks in advance.

(This is not a homework problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this proposition is not true. The easiest counterexample is the whole space $\Bbb R^{n+1}_1$ which contains lightlike vector, but is non-degenerate, or, any full Minkowski-subspace $\Bbb R^{k+1}_1\,$.

Your characterisation gives exactly the cleanly spacelike and the cleanly timelike subspaces.

Comment: Oops, it's kinda embarrassing that I missed the trivial cases. No wonder I can't find a proof. Thank you for stopping me from investing more time...